# Linux Devuan Beowulf apt-get update gives weird message of Skipping acquire of configued file sdklfflj

Tags: linux, apt, devuan

When I run `apt-get update` on Linux Devuan Beowulf I get:

```
Hit:1 http://deb.devuan.org/merged beowulf InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.devuan.org/merged beowulf-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.devuan.org/merged beowulf-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-sdklfflj/Packages'
as repository 'http://deb.devuan.org/merged beowulf InRelease' doesn't
support architecture 'sdklfflj'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-sdklfflj/Packages'
as repository 'http://deb.devuan.org/merged beowulf-security
InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'sdklfflj'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-sdklfflj/Packages'
as repository 'http://deb.devuan.org/merged beowulf-updates InRelease'
doesn't support architecture 'sdklfflj'
```

Any idea on what needs to be fixed/changed?

Note the /etc/apt/sources.list contains:

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Devuan GNU/Linux 3.1 beowulf i386 - desktop 20210315]/ beowulf contrib main non-free

#deb cdrom:[Devuan GNU/Linux 3.1 beowulf i386 - desktop 20210315]/ beowulf contrib main non-free

deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged beowulf main
deb-src http://deb.devuan.org/merged beowulf main

deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged beowulf-security main
deb-src http://deb.devuan.org/merged beowulf-security main

# beowulf-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged beowulf-updates main
deb-src http://deb.devuan.org/merged beowulf-updates main
```

Comment: This indicates you've been adding some /etc/apt/ sources list, added that "random" string there, and then forgot about it. Undo that edit, and things will work.

Comment: I added the sources.list that exists ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`.

If the output includes `sdklfflj`, then `dpkg --remove-architecture skdlfflj` should be the right fix for it.

But on the other hand, if `dpkg --print-architecture` outputs `sdklfflj`, then something might be more seriously wrong.